# Convert datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

How can we convert the time in AM/PM to 24-hrs format in MySQL? Example 2:50 PM should be converted to 14:50. Please help me to convert this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `%p` with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(  '2:50 pm',  '%h:%i %p' ) // will return 14:50:00
```